# Need Help with "Format View" feature in Modern List based on Condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, json-formatting, view-formatting

I am trying to color code a Row based on a condition in a Modern List (SPO).  It goes something like this:

In English:
**If ApprovalStatus = 'Pending' AND 'RequestDate' < [Today]-5
Then Row Color = 'Red'**

This is what I have so far, but it does not work.

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if(AND[$ApprovalStatus] == 'Pending', [$RequestDate] < [Today]-5), 'sp-field-severity--severeWarning','')"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do the comparison against the current date, you need to use the `@now`. Also, you need to calculate a date 5 days back from today. So, you need to subtract 5 days worth of milliseconds, (`5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 432000000`).

So, try using below JSON code:

```
{
    "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
    "additionalRowClass": "=if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Pending' && [$RequestDate] < @now-432000000, 'sp-field-severity--severeWarning', '')"
}
```

**References**:

1. [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)
2. [SharePoint Online Custom Format View issue with @now and UK Date format](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2019/03/09/sharepoint-online-custom-format-view-issue-with-now-and-uk-date-format/)

Comment: That worked! Thank You.